# Reading in input from text file, Bash script

Tags: bash, text-files, stdin

I am new to writing scripts in Bash and I am working on an assignment to make an inventory system. I have written all the scripts and they all work from using the standard input terminal. I now am looking to take the inputs from a text file called a1Input.txt which has all inputs on a new line.

```
r
9823
r
5430
c
7777
sml_widget
Small Widget (1 oz.)
6.99
15
50
Small, white, widget w/o packaging
r
7777
d
9823
r
9823
r
3293
u
3293


29.99
33
75


r
3293
```

The code for my initial bash script is this

```
#!/bin/bash

# assign1.bash

shopt -s nocasematch

option=""
until [ "$option" = "F" ]; do
echo "C - create a new item"
echo "R - read an existing item"
echo "U - update an existing item"
echo "D - delete an existing item"
echo "T - total price of an item"
echo "Choose a option"
read option
case $option in
C)
./create.bash
;;R)
./read.bash
;;U)
./update.bash
;;D)
./delete.bash
;;T)
./total.bash
;;*) 
echo "Invalid input"



esac
done
```

Comment: `..... esac done <a1Input.txt` ? [bashfaq how to read a file line by line](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: When did you get `q: Command not found.` ? Did you edit the file and try to quit with `:!q` (should be `:q!`) ? Or is the script called `q` and you gave `q` (should be `./q`) on the commandline ?

Answer (score 0):

What i would do to inject inputs from file to an interactive script is just:

```
cat a1Input.txt | ./interactive_script.sh
```

For example, imagine this simple script (copy-paste on terminal to create):

```
cat << EOF > questions.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "What's your name ?"
read name
echo "What is your favourite movie ?"
read movie
echo "Hi \$name, i also love '\$movie' movie !!"
EOF
```

And these inputs:

```
cat << EOF > inputs.txt
Edu
Interstellar
EOF
```

Then, just execute:

```
chmod a+x questions.sh
cat inputs.txt | ./questions.sh
```

If your script is more complicated, consider using "expect", although this is quite complex.

BRs